# How to negate the result of a function pointer created by mem_fn

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a more complex version of a wrapper class, which encapsulates std::vector of a user type like below.

```
struct UserType1Encapsulator
{
   template <typename F>
   UserType1Encapsulator& Filter( F filterFunction )
   {
       std::vector<userType1> newList;
       for ( size_t i = 0; i < iTerrainList.size(); i++)  --> can't use range for loop vs2010 
       {
           if ( filterFunction(iTerrainList[i]) )
               newList.push_back(iTerrainList[i]);

       }
       encapsulatedList = newList;
       return *this;
   }

std::vector<userType1> encapsulatedList;
}
```

I am doing some chaining stuff like Filter.Filter.Map etc..

Everything was nice until I find out I need to negate operation on the function pointer which I am passing like

```
   userVec.Filter( std::mem_fn(&userType1::isCopy) );
```

I need to use something like

```
userVec.Filter( std::not1( std::mem_fn(&userType1::isCopy)) );
```

But I am not sure how to use it and unfortunately I don't have access to lamdbas since even I am compiling with GCC 4.8 now code also should compile with vs2010.

What is the correct method to negate the result of std::mem_fn and which will compile in vs2010 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't have lambdas, remember that they are just syntactical sugar for callable objects. Create your own generic negation callable:

```
template <typename TFunction>
struct negator
{
    // `_f` will be your mem_fn
    TFunction _f;

    negator(TFunction f) : _f(f) { }

    bool operator()(/* same arguments as isCopy */) const
    {
        return !f(/* same arguments as isCopy */);
    }
};

template <typename TFunction>
negator<TFunction> make_negator(TFunction f)
{
    return negator<TFunction>(f);
}
```

You should then be able to use it as follows:

```
userVec.Filter( make_negator( std::mem_fn(&userType1::isCopy)) );
```

[**full wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nLhJ4r8Oidsvw4ul)

Comment: Thanks good remainder. In my case I may need this syntactical sugar because reviewers are not familiar with functional patterns will not like such long objects

Comment: No lambdas = no syntactical sugar. Find better reviewers :P

Comment: I used this solution for now still hoping something lighter like std::not1 , std::unary_negation etc...